# WPF custom user interface not appearing in

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I have a problem with custom UI library for WPF. I use https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf. So my problem is that when I ran it for the first time, this modern design appeared in my Visual Studio XAML designer. But when I opened project today after some time (or on another computer), modern UI didn't appear in Visual Studio XAML designer. I'm lost and don't know why is it happening.

Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual studio currently does not support running project code in Designer for projects that targets to ARM or X64 - see. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/debugging-or-disabling-project-code-in-xaml-designer?view=vs-2019

> For projects that target ARM or X64 processors, Visual Studio cannot run project code in the designer, so the Disable project code button is disabled in the designer.

Simply change your target architecture to x32, or Any CPU and check Project code button again.